# how to remove Jtable header grid lines

Tags: java, swing

How to remove Jtable Header grid lines, I am able to remove grid lines from rows but its gives grid lines in jtable header. Is it possible to remove Jtable header grid lines.

Comment: yes, there are Borders, but mouse event will be highlighting only one column, required most of code for that, remove JTableHeader and put there JMenuBar (BoxLayout) with JLabel??? instead :-)

Comment: @mKorbel can you please provide me sample code to remove grid lines from jtable header

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it possible to remove JTable header grid lines.*

Just curious: Why would you want to do that?

Now the answer: No it's not. Table header rendering depends on both [TableHeaderUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TableHeaderUI.html) implementation provided by the [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and [JTableHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html)'s renderer. You can tell the renderer you don't want borders but if L&F uses a custom painter with borders (f.i.: [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)) then you still have borders.

There are (poor) workarounds though, as described in other answers, but all of them have their limitations.

#### Providing a custom renderer

In order to keep tables header's rendering most similar to the original as possible, wich means no losing columns DnD effect, icons when sorting is applied, etc., I'd go with my own renderer as follows:

```
public class TableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private final TableCellRenderer baseRenderer;

    public TableHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer baseRenderer) {
        this.baseRenderer = baseRenderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent)baseRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
        return c;
    }
}
```

Then you can use default renderer as base for the new renderer, like this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
table.setShowGrid(false);

TableCellRenderer baseRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableHeaderRenderer(baseRenderer));
```

However its functioning depends on the L&F: this won't work with Nimbus, for example.

#### Playing with UIManager properties

As @blackbishop states, you can use UIManager to set a property to tell the L&F it must not draw table header cells border. However there's no convention about these properties (each L&F has its own properties) and most L&F will probably ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [JTableHeader without the grid lines](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1482871?start=0&tstart=0):

```
table.setShowGrid(false);
table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
```

You may also need to look at the previous (much longer) answer as well.

The following code (from the above link) shows a `jTable` with no gridlines (in the table **or** the header)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableHeaderTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] headers = {
            "column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"
        };
        String[][] data = new String[4][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = "item " + (i * data[0].length + j + 1);
            }
        JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
        for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setHeaderRenderer(new HeaderRenderer());
        }
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class HeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                   Object value,
                                                   boolean hasFocus,
                                                   boolean isSelected,
                                                   int row,
                                                   int col)
    {
        setText(value.toString());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not remove grid lines from table header but it will remove grid lines from jtable rows.

Comment: Like I said look at the longer example. Works for me. Code added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do that using the [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TableHeader.cellBorder" , BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
```

**Note :** This will not change the TableHeader cell borders of one JTable but for all the JTables in your application. This because you are changing the attribute of the Look and Feel
which manages the entire application. So all `TableHeader.cellBorder` are modified.

Comment: this worked for me and it is very simple code to put as it effects to all jtables in application